Is it safer to sarcastically say "This is not a scam" than honestly say "This is a scam"?
It is a thing that youtubers get sued for calling out scams.  One "solution" is to sarcastically say something non-defamatory while making it clear you mean the opposite.  I am fairly sure this is done here for comedic rather than legal effect but it shows what I mean:

So look, I am not saying that this is a scam.  For legal reasons I would never even hint at the possibility that a product might be a scam.  Indeed, I want to make it really clear that I have definitely not said it’s a scam. But what do you  think? Is it a scam? Let me know in the comments.

Assuming the intended meaning is not in doubt, could saying this be found to be non-defamatory where saying "This is a scam" would be defamatory?

A comment can only be defamatory if it is proven to be wrong. So I think the lawsuit will not hold, unless the suer can proove that it is not a scam and the youtuber ought to have known. Very unlikely.

It's a Frivolous lawsuit, and if I were the judge, I would dismiss with prejudice.

@PMF That is not the question.  Note I say "where saying "This is a scam" would be defamatory".

@User65535 I understand that, but I have a hard time thinking about a situation where this could be defamatory. Maybe something more serious would need to have been said.

@PMF You see the first link is about a high profile youtuber being sued for calling out what appears to be an obvious scam by a higher profile youtuber.

@User65535 Unless I'm missing something, that case has not been decided, so we don't know whether this is really defamatory.

@PMF It doesn't matter how it's decided. They were still sued, it wasn't dismisssed, and have to spend time and money defending themselves.

@Barmar  How does the verdict not matter? Cases are only dismissed as frivolous when they are absurd, not when they are similar to what the OP is discussing.

@Barmer because defendant only had recently received it. Motions to dismiss are most likely in the making.

@MikeB Unless they can counter-sue for legal fees, they still have to spend money defending the claim, regardless of the verdict.

If one wanted a safer word than "scam" one might say that it "looks suspicious" which is arguably a statement of opinion rather than one that implies facts.

@PMF : sadly, in some jurisdictions it's not the accuser who has to prove your statement wrong, it's you who have to prove it's not defamatory. And even worse, in some jurisdictions it can be defamatory even if it is true, if the other side can prove that their honour war hurt etc..

In the case of the second link, you need to have watched it. "They are claiming 3000% efficiency. ... I can't call this a scam, this is not a scam.".

Solution to what? You can still have the suit brought against you, which is the expensive and undesirable part.

'Scam' doesn't come into this.
The Question is a thinly disguised advertisement for services no-one has any idea how many SE Members might be interested in.
The Question is pretty-much a text-book case of 'Spam'

@RobbieGoodwin What services do you think the question is advertising?  The two links are to youtube videos from high profile "influencers".  I have no association with these accounts.

The second link is from a German YouTuber so would presumably fall under German law.

I suggest the Question remains as bogus as it was unnecessarily complicated and still, essentially, meaningless.
Again, 'scam' seems irrelevant here and  still 'spam' seems a fair description of the Question.
Like everyone here, you yourself are welcome to prove me wrong simply by re-wording the Question. Why not try that?

england-and-wales

Assuming the intended meaning is not in doubt, could saying this be found to be non-defamatory where saying "This is a scam" would be defamatory?

If the statement seems to be implying that something is a scam, e.g. by sarcastically saying "this is definitely NOT a scam," it might be found defamatory. Defamation is  not solely about the literal meaning of the statement, it's about whether a statement has a 'defamatory tendency'.
As the court said in McAlpine v Bercow:


As a matter of law, words are defamatory of a claimant if (1) they refer to that claimant and (2) they substantially affect in an adverse manner the attitude of other people towards the claimant, or have a tendency so to do.


A statement may be defamatory in its 'natural and ordinary' meaning or by 'innuendo'. In Jones v Skelton the court explained that:

The ordinary and natural meaning of words may be either the literal meaning or it may be an implied or inferred or an indirect meaning: any meaning that does not require the support of extrinsic facts passing beyond general knowledge but is a meaning which is capable of being detected in the language used can be a part of the ordinary and natural meaning of words. …. The ordinary and natural meaning may therefore include any implication or inference which a reasonable reader guided not by any special but only by general knowledge and not fettered by any strict legal rules of construction would draw from the words.

An innuendo meaning is one that can be implied from the statement only if the reader/listener also knows 'extrinsic facts' that are not general knowledge.
In respect of "safe" I would add that even if an accusation of defamation is dismissed or doesn't reach court at all, it can nevertheless cost the accused a lot of money, stress and time.

It's not quite clear from your answer - are 'natural and ordinary' and 'innuendo' mutually exclusive terms?

canada
You stipulate that "the intended meaning is not in doubt" and that they "mak[e] it clear" they "mean the opposite." What matters is the meaning that the ordinary person would infer from the words. That meaning is what will be assessed for defamation.
The impugned statement may convey more than its literal meaning
Courts recognize that meaning is contextual. It is not enough for a defendant to argue that a defamatory statement is literally true, if the defamatory sting of the comment stems from non-literal meaning.
In Canada, (see Weaver v. Corcoran, 2017 BCCA 160, at para. 71):

Words may convey a defamatory meaning literally, inferentially or by legal innuendo. Literal meaning is conveyed directly; inferential meaning, indirectly; and legal innuendo, by extension based on extrinsic facts. ...
Where the literal meaning of words is in issue, it is unnecessary to go beyond the words themselves to prove that they are defamatory.  Where a claim is based on the inferential meaning of words, the question is one of impression: what would the ordinary person infer from the words in the context in which they were used?  Both literal and inferential defamatory meaning reside within the words, as part of their natural and ordinary meaning.  In contrast, where legal innuendo is pleaded the impugned words take on defamatory meaning from outside circumstances beyond general knowledge, but known to the recipient.

Terminology
As an aside, to address an issue arising in the comments to the question: whether a statement is defamatory is separate from whether it is true or false. In Canada, for example, a statement is defamatory as long as it "would tend to lower the plaintiff’s reputation in the eyes of a reasonable person" (Grant v. Torstar Corp., 2009 SCC 61). And in the United States, courts also separate the two concepts. See for example, Pegasus v. Reno Newspapers, Inc., 118 Nev. 706 (Nev. 2003)

The general elements of a defamation claim require a plaintiff to prove: "(1) a false and defamatory statement...

Many defamatory statements are not grounds for tort liability in defamation because they are true.

Ok, above I assumed that a statement cannot be defamatory unless proven false. That seems to push freedom of expression a bit to far, but your explication seems to indicate that at least a statement cannot be defamatory if it is proven true. Am I right?

Sure the truth can reduce someones reputation. If I publish messages like "Bob has been convicted several times for his ponzy schemes" that won't help when he tries to set up his next scam. But then its not a case for a defamatory lawsuit (assuming that it is true, of course).

Sorry for being unclear. I was just making an example. I think we agree here.


Is it safer to sarcastically say "This is not a scam" than honestly say "This is a scam"?

It is safest to not use the word “scam”.

Scam:  “a dishonest scheme; a fraud.”


Fraud:  “wrongful or criminal deception intended to result in financial or personal gain.”

The problem with either of the options you presented is that the word "scam" is a conclusion of, (or claim made by...) the video producer that implies knowledge of intent. Since criminal intent to deceive cannot be positively determined outside a court of law, just report the facts as they are known and avoid using that word. Let the viewer decide...
Because truth and facts are never defamatory, while claiming that someone has criminal intent may be.
There’s nothing wrong, however, with attempting to lead the viewer into this conclusion - you have that right under freedom of speech and freedom of the press.  But in the court of public opinion it would be safest to not make public your own personal verdict.

The intend applies to the gain part which is fairly obvious for any for-profit company.

@quarague, yes, it's so obvious that you really didn't need to point it out.

Whether the use of the word "scam" is intended to imply a criminal action would be a matter for the court to decide on in most jurisdictions. Simply stitching together some dictionary definitions in this fashion would not suffice.

@JackAidley, I don't disagree.  But do you agree there is some risk of the term being judged defamatory?  Because that's really all I'm saying.

The term "scam" is often used to describe things which are perfectly legal, but are often purveyed with the hope that people won't understand what's actually being offered.  If carved marble figurine of a certain size would normally sell for $1000 and plastic replicas for $5, a listing that offers a plastic replica for $750 might be described as a scam even if someone who paid the $750 would receive a well-packed item that precisely matched the listing description; whether such a person "got scammed" would depend upon why they chose the listing in question.

@supercat, Ok... and I said that using the term expresses an opinion.  So your points are valid, but I'm unsure if the feedback is intended to inform me, or influence an edit to my answer.  What was your intent in commenting here?

My point was that although the definition includes the term "fraud", the term "fraud" has a legal meaning, and the fact that the notion of "scam" is opinion-based would suggest that the term in and of itself isn't defamatory.  Misconstruing facts to suggest that something is a scam could constitute defamation regardless of whether one mentions the term "scam", and I think because "scam" is opinon-based (unlike fraud, which is legally definable) I would think it safer than alternatives.

@supercat, got it, thx.  On a spectrum with an accusation of Fraud at one end and a simple statement of fact at the other, "scam" is somewhere in between.  Not using it at all is less risky than using it is the point of my answer...

Your answer has it backwards. Only a factual claim can give rise to liability because only a factual claim can be proven false. An opinion about intent can never give rise to liability because there is no way it could create a false factual impression in any reasonable reader or listener because a reasonable person knows that we have no way to read other people's minds. It is perfectly safe to speculate about things that cannot be proven false because one who alleges defamation has the burden to prove falsity.

@DavidSchwartz, but a "factual claim" proven false is not a "fact" at all, it is merely a refuted "claim" that must be either a lie or a mistake. I recommended to report facts only, and not make any other sort of claim. (specifically claims that imply an intent to "scam" people)  Facts cannot be defamatory, because by definition they are true. And I agree that some opinion based speculation on motive based on the facts would be safe, I touched on that in the last paragraph about leading the viewer to form their own possible conclusion. So I disagree that I have things backwards.

P.S.  I did make a few minor edits to my answer as a result of your feedback.  Please let me know if this alters your perspective...

Your answer is still quite bad. It suggests that one increases ones risk of losing a defamation claim by making assertions that cannot be proven. But the truth is almost always the reverse because such claims generally cannot be proven false and to prevail in a claim for defamation, you must prove the claim false. You are absolutely free to speculate about things that can neither be proven nor disproven.

By the way, the definition of "factual" is "concerned with what is actually the case rather than opinions or interpretations". If it is possible to prove that a claim is true or that it is false, then it is a factual claim.

@DavidSchwartz, A few points:  1.)  I do not address risk of losing a defamation suit, I suggest reducing the risk of a claim being brought in the first place by avoiding provocative language.  2.)  Your point that a plaintiff must prove a claim false would seem to bolster my recommendation that by sticking to truth and facts the defendant would prevail.  Am I missing something?  3.)  I never used the term ""factual"*, (pertaining to, characterised by, or connected with...) I used "facts", i.e. provable truths, NOT disprovable fact-like claims.

united-states
It is possible this would be a factual question for a jury to decide. The jury would see the video itself, and (perhaps) hear testimony from expert witnesses on one or both sides as to how the public tends to interpret statements of this variety, and would then be asked to rule on the meaning a "reasonable viewer" would interpret the video to have. On the other hand, you say that "the intended meaning is not in doubt," which suggests that the defense has already conceded the issue, and so there would be nothing to litigate on this point.
However, that is not the end of the story. There would be several additional steps both before and after that ruling which would need to be considered.

If the lawsuit were originally filed in a jurisdiction other than the United States (and the already-victorious plaintiff is now trying to get a US court to enforce the foreign judgment by attaching the American assets of the defendant), a US judge would have to rule on whether that jurisdiction provides similar free speech protections to those of the US as provided in 28 USC 4102, and if not, whether the plaintiff would have won anyway in a US court. In practice, the latter half of this test is equivalent to holding a whole new trial in the US, and the former half is unlikely to be satisfied by any jurisdiction because the actual malice standard is more or less unique to the US.

For lawsuits originally filed in the US, this step is skipped.


A YouTuber is a "user of an interactive computer service" within the meaning of 47 USC 230(c)(1), so the YouTuber could argue that the information was "provided by another information content provider." This might become relevant if the YouTuber was merely relaying information that they had obtained from some third party. In practice, this provision has more often been used to protect platforms such as YouTube and not individuals, but the law very explicitly does protect users as well as platforms, so it's not a completely impossible defense. Still, this is not raised frequently, and I'm not sure it's a very useful defense in practice.

Note that this liability shield is incorporated by reference into 28 USC 4102, so it provides yet another off-ramp to recognition of a foreign libel judgment.


The plaintiff would need to demonstrate the falsity of the YouTuber's claim. It is not sufficient to merely demonstrate that the scheme was not literally a crime - US courts have recognized the doctrine of "substantial truth," where the court will consider the "gist or sting" of the defendant's statement rather than its literal meaning. If the plaintiff was offering a product under false or misleading marketing or branding, it is likely that a US court would rule that the term "scam" was substantially true even if no literal crime had been committed, because an ordinary consumer would understand "scam" to encompass a broader sense of "a good or service that is worthless or does not function as advertised" and not the hyper-literal meaning of "a fraudulent scheme that violates one or more laws."

Of course, there are limits. The more specific and objective the YouTube video is, the less plausible this defense becomes. Saying "I tried the ACME Corporation's widgets, and they didn't work. They're a total scam!" is a very different thing from saying "The ACME Corporation is operating a massive scam in the widget market. They are defrauding customers by selling a product that doesn't work, can't work, and in fact is physically impossible." The latter is not going to be defensible if it turns out that the widgets do work but have a high defect rate, whereas the former is more of a gray area, and might be taken to be opinion based on disclosed facts - since an opinion cannot be true or false, that would be a victory for the defendant.
Substantial truth is also evaluated in the context where the statement appears. A five minute YouTube video that is filled with memes, jokes, and other nonsense is likely to be viewed more favorably than a two hour YouTube video with a serious tone throughout, because a reasonable audience understands that the former is prone to hyperbole and exaggeration, and may even be a work of satire, whereas the latter is more likely to be taken seriously. But if you start the video by telling the audience that they should take you seriously despite the memes and other nonsense, then that would tend to cut against this defense. There's no free lunch - if you present something that audiences will take seriously, then you assume a greater risk of getting sued if you get your facts wrong.


The plaintiff would probably be (at least) a limited purpose public figure, since they are offering products for sale to the general public and (presumably) advertising those products. Therefore, they would need to demonstrate "actual malice" - meaning the defendant either knew the statement was false, or was reckless as to its truth or falsity. In practice, "recklessness" usually involves disregarding evidence against the statement. Mere carelessness is not enough.


united-states

Assuming the intended meaning is not in doubt, could saying this be found to be non-defamatory where saying "This is a scam" would be defamatory?

If the intended meaning matches the meaning a reasonable reader or listener would understand in context, then the exact words you chose do not matter. The test of whether a statement is defamatory or not is done on what the statement means.
For the same reason, you cannot generally put "it is my opinion that" before a defamatory statement to make it non-defamatory even if it is in fact your opinion. Unless a reasonable person listening to the statement in context would understand that prefix to change your claim from a factual claim to some other claim, it has no effect on whether the statement is actionable defamation or not.
If a reasonable person hearing the statement in context would understand, "This is definitely not a scam. I certainly would never say this is a scam." to mean that the speaker is saying that it is in fact a scam, then the legal effect is precisely the same as if you said any other words that would convey the same impression such as, "this is a scam".
There is no magic words test for defamation. All that matters it the meaning the speaker intended to convey and the meaning that a reasonable listener hearing the statement in context would likely understand to be conveyed.
The point of defamation law is protect against people being able to create false beliefs about other people that harm their reputations. If you could create such beliefs and cause that harm while using artful word selection to avoid liability, defamation law would just be a minor challenge rather than a real protection from harm society has deemed to be justifiably punished.
